# Mysql always returns 1 for rows affected

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, jdbi

I have a java application using JDBI/JDBC/Mysql.

I am trying to run some update statements as a transaction i.e setting autoCommit(false). When i execute the statement JDBI is always returning number of rows affected as 1, even when i expect it to return 0

Here is the code snippet.

```
DBI dbi = currShardHandle.getDBI();

//Open the connection once for each shard
Handle h = dbi.open();

handleList.add(h);
//set AutoCommit to false to start transaction
h.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

List<TransactionQuery> list = shardQueryMap.get(shardId);
for(TransactionQuery query: list) {
    currQuery = query;
    Update u = h.createStatement(query.getQuery());
    log.info("commit(). Query {}",query.getQuery());

    //Bind parameters
    int pos = 0;
    for(Object obj: query.getParams()) {
        if(obj == null)
            u.bindNull(pos++, java.sql.Types.JAVA_OBJECT);
        else
            u.bind(pos++, obj.toString());
    }

    u.setQueryTimeout(dbTimeout);
    try {

        int count = u.execute();
        log.debug("Rows Modified {} , Rewritten SQL {} ", count, u.getContext().getRewrittenSql());
        rowsModified += count;
    } finally {
        //.....
    }
}
```

SQL inserts that i am running are of type

```
INSERT into abc (x,y,z ) values (1,2,3) on duplicate key update z=z;
```

When I run the same query in mysql client, it shows me rows affected as 0.

Answer (score 2):

I found that there was a bug reported in mysql 5.1. Here is the link for the bug

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39352

I added useAffectedRows=true in my JDBC Url and it fixed the issue.